# Excel formula where first digit in column a returns year and second digit in column a returns month

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xls

I need the first digit in column A to return a year and the second digit in column A to return a month in column B.  For instance, the code is 3A21CY1C in Column A.  I need it to return 2013 (first digit- 3) and January (second digit - A), so column B will read Jan-2013.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: there are not so many excel functions to make substring, convert char to number, concatenate strings and create date from string

Answer (score 1):

`=TEXT(DATE(CONCATENATE("201",LEFT(A1,1)),FIND(MID(A1,2,1),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",1),1),"MMM-YYYY")`

Comment: Thanks for the formula.  Where do I change this formula to refer it to the cell in the column before it?

Comment: If you put this formula in B1, it will point to the cell in the column before it (A1). Change A1 (both occurences) to the cell you want to reference (doesn't need to be in the column before, could be any cell). 

If you found the answer useful, please mark it as accepted. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should put an actual date into column B and use a custom number format of *mmm-yyyy*. In B1,

```
=DATE(2010+LEFT(A1), CODE(MID(A1, 2, 1))-64, 1)
```

That will put *01/01/2013* into B1. Use cell formatting of *mmm-yyyy* to get a true date showing *Jan-2013*.

If you have to have a text representation of a date, wrap this in the [TEXT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-20D5AC4D-7B94-49FD-BB38-93D29371225C) and use the same formatting mask.

```
=TEXT(DATE(2010+LEFT(A1), CODE(MID(A1, 2, 1))-64, 1), "mmm-yyyy")
```

[image: Date from String]